# Object property with ellepsis instead of a dot: Object = { ...Object }

Tags: javascript, angular, object, javascript-objects

In an angular 4 project, there is this line of code `this.config = { ...this.config }`. After some checking, it seems that it did not change `this.config`. But removing that line, breaks the change detection for `this.config`.

Here is the component that is using the object

`<dp-date-picker config="config"> </dp-date-picker>`

This is the only function that modifies `this.object`

```
  private updateConfig(value, key) {
   if (!this.config) {
      this.config = {};
   }
   this.config[key] = value;
   this.config = { ...this.config }; // why does this work?
  }
```

Can anybody explain what `this.config = { ...this.config }` does?

Comment: Look up object spread. It makes a shallow copy of the original object.

Comment: Probably something else modifies `this.config` after this assignment? Please post the complete code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks.

Comment: @bergi will update. thanks.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's a well worded question asking about something that's genuinely confusing. Even if you know what object spread is, it's not readily clear why this is being done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an object, you create a memory reference. Spreading an object into another creates a copy of this object, but in a different memory reference.

Let's picture this :

```js
const obj = { id: 1, sub: { id: 11 } };
const copy = { ...obj };

console.log(obj === copy); // false
console.log(obj.sub === copy.sub); // true
console.log(obj.id === copy.id); // true
```

As you can see, both objects don't have the same memory reference, but the sub-objects have, and the primitive values are compared as values, not as references.

This means that when writing

```
this.config = { ...this.config };
```

You actually create a new memory reference, deleting the previous one.

In Angular, creating a new memory reference triggers a change detection. If you remove the piece of code, nothing happens anymore because you touche a memory reference into the object (sub-object), not the object itself.

To trigger a change detection, you can either use the spreading, or the `ChangeDetectorRef.prototype.detectChanges` function.

I hope it answered your question !

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense now.